# Inplementation of LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm using Keras using Tensorflow backend.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value = 0., input_shape = (MAX_LENGTH, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(16, input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, MAX_LENGTH, 1), return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dense(units = 2))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

This python code works, but I wonder whether there are 16 LSTM blocks with 1 cell each, or 1 LSTM block with 16 cells.

Thanks in advance!

[image: LSTM architecture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so your question got me thinking and I think I over did it but here goes nothing.
Here's a snippet of code I did to get some insights behind the LSTM implementation.

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(20, 30), return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
weights = model.get_weights()
```

Now, by inspecting the weights shapes we can get an intuition on what's happening.

```
In [12]: weights[0].shape
Out[12]: (30, 40)
In [14]: weights[1].shape
Out[14]: (10, 40)
In [15]: weights[2].shape
Out[15]: (40,)
```

And here is a description of them:

```
In [26]: model.weights
Out[26]: 
[<tf.Variable 'lstm_4/kernel:0' shape=(30, 40) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'lstm_4/recurrent_kernel:0' shape=(10, 40) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'lstm_4/bias:0' shape=(40,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Those are the only weights available. I also went to see the Keras implementation on https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1765

So you can see that @gorjan was right, it implementes one cell, meaning the 4 gates (for the recurrent input as well as the sequence input), along with their biases.

The "layer" thinking here should be applied to the number of times the LSTM will be unrolled, in this case 30.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Now, I understand that keras implements one cell whose dimension corresponds the number of units. Some people call the dimension of a cell as "number of cells", so I was coufused. In your example, number of units is 10, number of features is 30, number of timesteps is 20, right? So, I'm afraid to ask    if the `number of times the LSTM will be unrolled` is 20.

Comment: Yeap its confusing. You can think of these units as 'neurons' in a standard Dense layer as they are then used by gates. Glad I could help. How about accepting it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, Thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's for 1 block, 16 cells, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using cells `LSTM, GRU`, you don't have the notion of layers per se. What you actually have is a cell, that implements few gates. Each of the gates constitutes of a separate weight matrix that the model will learn during training. For example, in your case, what you will have is 1 cell, where each of the gates defined by matrices will have a dimension `(feature_size_of_your_input, 16)`. I suggest that you read: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/ really carefully before you start implementing this kind of stuff. Otherwise, you are just using them as a black box model without understanding what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my poor explanation. There might be a problem of terminology, but I'm afraid to ask if your "cell" corresponds to "block" in the picture above and your "block" corresponds to a "layer" as well.